# Disable IR LED's on Leap Motion

Tags: motion-detection, leap-motion

I'm working on a project where we want to disable the three infrared LED's built into our Leap Motion controller so we can instead track an external infrared LED. We plan on determining the XYZ coordinates of this LED by applying triangulation to images pulled from our the controller's two sensors. I fear the functionality may be built into the board. Might it be possible to turn these three infared LED's off, while still being able to use the two sensors?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to turn the illuminator LEDs off through the API, config files or command line parameters. I'm not sure you need to, though. Have you tried seeing how visible your LED is under normal operating conditions? A small circle of retroreflective tape can also be used to create an easily visible dot in the sensor images.

If not, your only recourse might be to disable the LEDs physically. You would want to do that in a reversible manner, though, so that you could still recalibrate the sensors. [Sparkfun did a teardown of a Leap Motion device](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/leap-motion-teardown), which shows how you might approach this task.

Comment: We actually ended up just pulling the LED's out. Understand though, we were doing this during a hackathon. We rationalized that our time was more valuable, I guess. Anyway, thanks for the answer! You gave the information I was looking for.

Comment: I guess there was more hack in that hack-a-thon then usual!